# php: soap client, get data from class

Tags: php, soap

i run soap client:

```
$dir = "http://address.com/?Version=1.0,wsdl=1";

$client = new SoapClient($dir);
```

And in this server is class:

```
all_user

    * return: array
    * access: public

all_user_dt[] get_user(string $id)

    * string $id
```

how get information from this class?
I try:

```
$client->all_user->get_user('213');
```

But is wrong, i get error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Unauthorized in C:\www\index.php:38 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...' ...
```

Comment: Hi, have you tryed the folowing code? `$client->get_user('213');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Uncaught SoapFault exception: HTTP **Unauthorized** ..." So I guess you're not allowed.
Tell SoapClient how to authenticate using the [`$options` parameter](http://php.net/soapclient.soapclient).

Comment: Hi, thanks for help ;) If i print: $client, i get SoapClient Object
(
    [_soap_version] => 1
    [sdl] => Resource id #4
)
So i think i connect successfully, or no?

Comment: Uh, no? The SoapClient uses HTTP (as in `$dir`). Why should it hold a connection open? This resource is presumably a handle of the WSDL file. But even if this is indeed a TCP socket, the message clearly indicates an error at a higher layer in the protocol stack. I repeat: Authenticate!